# General solution of this differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I got a bit stuck at this equation below :

$$ty^{'}\cos(y) + \sin(y) =\sin^2y,y(0)=1$$

This is what I did :

$$ty^{'}\cos(y) = \sin^2(y) - \sin(y)$$
$$t\frac{dy}{dt}\cos(y) = \sin(y)( \sin(y) - 1 ) $$
$$t\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{\sin(y)( \sin(y) - 1 )}{\cos(y)} $$
$$\frac{\cos(y)}{\sin(y)( \sin(y) - 1 )} . dy= dt \frac{1}{t}$$
$$\int_{}{\frac{\cos(y)}{\sin(y)( \sin(y) - 1 )} . dy}= \int_{}{\frac{1}{t} dt }$$
$$ ln|1-\frac{1}{\sin(y)}|= ln|t| + C$$
Assuming $1 > 1/\sin(y)$
=> $$  \frac{1}{\sin(y)}= 1-e^Ct $$
$$(C =  e^C )$$
=>  $$  \frac{1}{\sin(y)}= 1 - C .t $$
$$  \sin(y)=  \frac{1}{1 - C .t} $$
$$    y   =  \sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{1 - C .t}) $$
Right now it's impossible to find C in this case , even if I try to set y to $0$ in the final equation I get :
$$y(0) = \sin^{-1}(1) $$
$$y(0) = \frac{\pi}{2} ≠ 1 $$

So now I have 2 problems :

- **y(0) is different than 1**
- **C is impossible to find in my case** .

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Easier to substitute $w=\sin y$
 The constant dosent exist, for $y(0)=1$

Comment: Note that $y=0$ is also a solution.

Comment: I think **given IVP** has no solution. Even $~y(t)=0~$ is not a solution as $~y(0)=1\ne0~.$

Comment: Yea turns out that there was a mistake in the excercice ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture below is a sketch of the numerical solution in the interval $[-10,10]$

I had to modify the initial value because with the given one I got no solutions.

$$t y' \cos y+\sin y=\sin ^2y,\;y(1)=1$$

---

[image]